# How can i save these type of while loop result into multiple data frame in python?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, while-loop

This is my sample code:

```
from window_slider import Slider
import numpy
list = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8])
bucket_size = 3
overlap_count = 0
slider = Slider(bucket_size,overlap_count)
slider.fit(list)       
while True:
    window_data = slider.slide()
    print(window_data)
    if slider.reached_end_of_list(): break
```

This shows me output:

```
[0 1 2]
[3 4 5]
[6 7 8]
```

if i tried to save it in a dataframe, it saves only the last values of  the numpy array that is [6 , 7 and 8] . I want to save them all in a different data frames can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Well, how is the dataframe supposed to look like?

Comment: like saving [0 1 2] in df1 then saving [3 4 5]in df2 and saving [6 7 8]in df3 and finally concatenating all these df1+df2+df3 into a new dataframe let's say df.

Comment: see my above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a dictionary:

```
d = {}
c = 0
while True:
    c += 1
    window_data = slider.slide()
    d['df%s'%c] = window_data
    if slider.reached_end_of_list(): break
```

After all, just use `d['df1']` and `d['df2']` and so on.. to access, if you want them to be accessed directly like `df1` and `df2`, add the below line to the end of the code:

```
locals().update(d)
```

Then `df1` and `df2` will work.

Comment: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'update  this is showing error when i added last line. "locals.update(d)"

Comment: @Logica Mistake on my end

Comment: Thank you so much you solved my issue. God bless you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lists to store it in a list of lists:

```
from window_slider import Slider
import numpy
import pandas as pd
list = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8])
bucket_size = 3
overlap_count = 0
slider = Slider(bucket_size,overlap_count)
slider.fit(list) 

#Master list which consists of all the lists of arrays
output_list = []      
while True:
    window_data = slider.slide()
    #Convert the window_data array to a list
    output_df_list = window_data.tolist()
    #Append the "output_df_list" to the master list "output_list"
    output_list.append(output_df_list)
    print(window_data)
    if slider.reached_end_of_list(): break
```

### Output:

```
print(output_list)
```

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```